# CSS doesn't link properly from the header file using base_url helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

My **header.php** doesn't link to **default.css** properly. Page loads without **CSS** applied.
If I view the source of the page and click on the link to **.css** file - **403 Forbidden** shows up in **Source View**.

**config.php**

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/dev/';`

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page/view";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**pages** *is the controller*

**view** *is the method*

**application/view/templates/header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

**application/css/default.css**

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

body {
    background-image: url(../images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

**application/images/**

`-- bg.gif GIF Image 1KB`

Comment: **403 Forbidden** -> check the **error log** of your webserver. It should **tell you more** what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: use `href="/application/css/default.css"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a good practice to put css files in "assets" directory instead of "application". Move the file to a directory called assets/css in your DOCUMENT_ROOT and change this line:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: i just want to add that you can include the files inside the base_url like `base_url('assets/css/default.css');` which become much more readable ..

Answer (score 0):

This is the default state of Codeigniter. You need to create a .htaccess file in your css and image directory and put this code (it should work, I am using it):

```
allow from All
```

Or you can create a public folder in the root folder and not have this problems.

Answer (score 0):

Leave base_url in config blank.Like this:

```
  $config['base_url'] = '';
```